# Mysql: null is being returned even if variable given as parameter is correct

Tags: c#, mysql

I keep getting a null value returned from my query even after checking in the debugger that the `loc` value is correct. What am I doing wrong?

```
     {
         myCommand.CommandText = "select idkooilist FROM locatie where id = @IDOP";
         myCommand.Parameters.Add("@IDOP", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = loc;
         {                 
              var count = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();    
              lockooid = Convert.ToInt64(count);
         }
    }
```

Comment: I just fixed your code format so it's more "readable"

Comment: If you run the query `select idkooilist FROM locatie where id = (whatever the value of loc is)` directly in the database, do you still get an empty set?

Comment: no i dont thats why i dont get it

Comment: How is 'id' defined? (what type of variable)? And, to David's question: exactly how do you run the SELECT against the database (taking C# out of the issue)?

Comment: int foreign key